# Unknown field specified for Model - datetime

Tags: django, model

I have this model:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=250)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I have also tried providing a default value for the due date but it also produces the error.

I have this generic view:

```
class ScheduleCreate(CreateView):
    model = Schedule
    fields = ['name', 'due_date']
```

PS: I have tried to changed  `due_date`  to CharField and it worked propely. I think the cause of the problem is the date time. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Either provide datetime default as:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=DEFAULT_EXPIRE_DAYS))
```

Or use:

`models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`

As your field name suggests I don't think this will be of much help

Try changing `due_date` to:-

`models.DateTimeField(editable=True)`

Comment: it displayed this error:  'due_date' cannot be specified for Schedule model form as it is a non-editable field